# use console.readline to assign a value to an index in an array c#

Tags: c#, arrays

I'm making a hangman game and I want to be able to take a user input from the console and assign it to the values in an array.

```
string hangWord;
char[] hangArray;

console.WriteLine("Please enter your hangman word.");
hangWord = console.Readline();
char[] hangArray = {hangWord}
```

how do I do this so that if a user enters a word like "shower"
the indexes will be 
    hangArray[] = {"s","h","o","w","e","r"};
automatically?

Comment: `char[] hangArray = hangWord.ToCharArray()`

Answer (score 1):

```
char[] hangArray = hangWord.ToCharArray()
```

Comment: `ToCharArray[]` - o_O

Comment: same was trying to edit but it's at least 6 chars to allow edition ... it's `.ToCharArray();` ;)

Comment: I should pay more attention. I must rely on squiggly underlines too much these days.